# VHDL Waveform Simulation Line/Spikes Anomaly

Tags: vhdl, simulation, modelsim, waveform

I'm currently building a n-bit subtractor, and it appears to be working fine, but my waveform has these anomalous lines that instantaneously come and go. I'm not sure what's causing them, and it's been bugging me for days. You can see the spikes happening for the "negative" signal - I suspect it's because of some concurrency issue but I have tried searching all kinds of keywords to find the root of this problem and haven't come up with anything:

[image]

Code:

One bit full adder

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity one_bit_full_adder is
  port (
    x, y, cin : in std_logic;
    sum, cout: out std_logic);
end one_bit_full_adder;

architecture arch of one_bit_full_adder is
  begin
    sum <= x xor y xor cin;
    cout <= (x and y) or (cin and (x xor y));
  end arch;
```

N-bit subtractor

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity n_bit_subtractor is
  generic(constant BIT_LENGTH : integer);
  port (
    a, b : in std_logic_vector(BIT_LENGTH - 1 downto 0);
    negative: out std_logic;
    difference: out std_logic_vector(BIT_LENGTH - 1 downto 0));
end n_bit_subtractor;

architecture arch of n_bit_subtractor is
  component one_bit_full_adder port (x, y, cin: in std_logic; sum, cout: out std_logic); end component;
  signal carry_ins: std_logic_vector(BIT_LENGTH downto 0) := (0 => '1', others => '0');
  signal differences: std_logic_vector(BIT_LENGTH - 1 downto 0);
  signal b_operand: std_logic_vector(BIT_LENGTH - 1 downto 0);

  begin
    b_operand <= not b;
    difference <= differences;
    negative <= differences(BIT_LENGTH - 1) and '1';
    adders: for i in 0 to BIT_LENGTH-1 generate
      H2: one_bit_full_adder port map(x=>a(i), y=>b_operand(i), cin=>carry_ins(i), sum=>differences(i), cout=>carry_ins(i+1));
    end generate;
  end arch;
```

Testbench:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity n_bit_subtractor_test is
end n_bit_subtractor_test;

architecture arch_test of n_bit_subtractor_test is
constant BIT_LEN : integer := 3;
component n_bit_subtractor is
  generic(constant BIT_LENGTH : integer);
  port (
    a, b : in std_logic_vector(BIT_LENGTH - 1 downto 0);
    negative: out std_logic;
    difference: out std_logic_vector(BIT_LENGTH - 1 downto 0));
end component n_bit_subtractor;
signal p0, p1, difference: std_logic_vector(BIT_LEN-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal negative: std_logic;
begin
  uut: n_bit_subtractor
    generic map (BIT_LENGTH => BIT_LEN)
    port map (a => p0, b => p1, difference => difference, negative => negative);

  process
  variable difference_actual: std_logic_vector(BIT_LEN-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
  begin
    for i in 0 to (2**BIT_LEN)-1 loop
      for k in 0 to (2**BIT_LEN)-1 loop
        wait for 200 ns;
        p1 <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(p1) + 1);
      end loop;
      p0 <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(p0) + 1);
    end loop;

    report "No errors detected. Simulation successful." severity failure;
  end process;

end arch_test;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The ModelSim version is v10.1d

Comment: You should not write full adder in VHDL and then connect them but instead write `a-b` and let the tools pick the gates for you. The verification time is shorter and it will oven generate smaller and faster designs.

Comment: Probably something fishy is going on in `one_bit_full_adder`, can you add its code as well?

Comment: Because you don't provide a [mcve] a reader is capable of authoring a `one_bit_full_adder` that produces a [more monotonic `negative` waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN0Y6.jpg) (`architecture foo of one_bit_full_adder is
begin
    sum <= x xor y xor cin;
    cout <= (x and y) or (x and cin) or (y and cin);
end architecture;`)

Comment: They are probably spikes caused by the iterations of your simulator (so-called delta cycles). A value is assigned to a signal and then on the next simulator iteration, a different value is assigned. And so on. This is how a VHDL simulator works. It is nothing to worry about. Some simulators don't display these spikes; Questasim/Modelsim does. (In fact, there is a special mode where you can zoom in an see what is going on in detail - read the manual.) For more information, google "VHDL delta cycle".

Comment: I would expect such spikes also in real hardware. Gates have different propagation times and so several "intermediate" results might show up. These spikes might be too short to measure with standard scopes, though.

Comment: Oh apologies, I forgot to add the one-bit full adder. I'm implementing the subtractor with my own full adder because the class assignment requires me to. It looks like such spikes may actually be because of delta cycles when I click "Enable Time Deltas Mode": https://i.imgur.com/5prkjX0.png as explained by https://vhdlwhiz.com/delta-cycles-explained/. This is odd though because I've never messed with any settings that would cause them to show up (ModelSim v10.1d)

Comment: Signals don't update while processes are executing. Here delta cycles result from signal assignment whose waveform element doesn't include an **after** *time_expression* defaulting to 0. Signals with events have the projected output waveform for the current simulation time replaced with the new waveform scheduled for the current simulation time and the next simulation cycle will be a delta cycle without simulation time advancing. This emulates sequential operation in an event  driven simulator with 0 delay signal assignments. You're seeing more than one delta cycle due to the carry chain.

Comment: I think the cause of the problem is the way one_bit_full_adder  is implemented. The code is written in a way causing the simulator to show spikes One thing I can think of that causes such an issue is a missing signal in sensitivity list. But without seeing the code of one_bit_full_adder it's hard to say.

Comment: @Simson nonsense. If the homework assignment says you should make it with logic gates, you should not make it with an arithmetic assignment.
@ OP: this is normal and this is the whole reason you use clocked logic in circuits: in real life electronics have latency. This causes small glitches. But on the next clock edge the signal will be good. In this simulation you see a 'glitch' but it is infinitesimal small in time (one delta cycle).